# Python: Is it possible to execute a VBScript script in Python?

Tags: python, vbscript

I am attempting to create a password manager that runs on startup and autofills passwords using a certain keybind.

Currently, when running on startup the application creates a window and I researched ways to make the window hidden and I have found a VBScript example that allows for this to happen.

The script I found goes as following:

```vb
Dim WShell
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WShell.Run "c:\x\myapp.exe", 0
Set WShell = Nothing
```

I have added code to detect if my program is being ran out of the Startup directory.

I am working on creating code to execute the VBScript in the Python file yet my function returns quite a meaningless exception I cannot understand.

My python function goes as following:

```py
def run_vbscript(script:str):
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    shell.Run(script)
```

The exception I currently am recieving goes as following:

`pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024894), None)`

Have I made any obvious mistake in my Python function which is preventing the VBScript from executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript are run using [`wscript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wscript).  So just call it passing your script as argument.

So your function would look like:

```
import subprocess

def run_vbscript(script:str):
    subprocess.run(['wscript', script])
```

---

But...

`WShell.Run` is just running [`WinExec` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winexec) from Windows API.  You can [pass to it the flag `SW_HIDE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) that does the same your VBScript is doing.

Even better, you can use [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), that also provides this feature, since `WinExec` is deprecated.

Check [Python for Win32 Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) for a way to call this function directly from Python code.  You're after [CreateProcess function](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32/win32process__CreateProcess_meth.html) and the parameter that holds the `SW_HIDE` flag is `startupinfo.wShowWindow`.